# How to take payment on edited PayPal order

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal, payment, payment-methods, edit-order

**Is it possible to re-authorise/re-take payment on the new order that is created when you 'Edit' an existing order?**

I'm running Magento 1.8.1.0 for a client's website that is currently in development. They will be using PayPal standard payments as their only payment method and I currently have this set up with my sandbox details for testing purposes.

- If a customer makes a purchase through the website using PayPal as the payment method, an order is created as usual.
- This order remains at status 'Pending Payment' until the customer completes the PayPal standard payment process, at which stage the PayPal IPN sends the transaction ID back to Magento and the order status is updated to 'Processing'.
- If the website admin then 'Edits' this order, a new order is created. This new order carries across the PayPal payer ID.

**At this stage, is it possible to capture payment for the new order?**

If I refund the original order within PayPal, the IPN notifies Magento which then automatically closes the original order and creates a credit memo. I'm just stuck at how to request/assign a new payment against the newly created order.